# Disable sticky table headers for field collection?

Tags: entities, theming

I'm using a field collection on my node form and sticky table headers comes baked in with no way to disable it (that I can find, anyway). How do I disable sticky table headers? Preferably with Javascript or CSS... sadly, I'm using an instance of Drupal 7 that has a lot of the internals hidden from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One line of CSS will do it:

```
table.sticky-header { display: none !important; }
```

Answer found [here](http://knackforge.com/blog/sivaji/drupal-disable-sticky-header-behavior-themetable).

Answer (score 1):

Just chiming in here since I came across this page while searching for a solution and wanted to demonstrate the alternative to a CSS override.

If you want to remove this at the theme level — where arguably it should be — you'll want to look at `theme_field_multiple_value_form`.

That function calls `theme('table'... w/out sending the 'sticky' => FALSE value)` see [`theme_table`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7).

If you override that function and set `'sticky' => FALSE`, then the code that initialized the sticky header will be ignored.

If you want to only override this for a certain field, just reference the `$variables['element']['#field_name']` value.

Comment: Agree that it should be removed at the theme layer and not in css. The problem is that 'theme_field_multiple_value_form' creates blobs of HTML and doesn't return a render array, so developers are left forking the entire function to get in there. At this stage I'm looking at the lesser of two evils.